# Docker - Windows IIS image - 'Remove-Website' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: asp.net, docker, docker-container, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I am trying to run my **ASP.NET Web API** on a docker container on **Windows 2016 server**. Here is my docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY TestWebAPI/*.csproj ./TestWebAPI/
COPY TestWebAPI/*.config ./TestWebAPI/
RUN nuget restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY TestWebAPI/. ./TestWebAPI/
WORKDIR /app/TestWebAPI
RUN msbuild /p:Configuration=Release

FROM microsoft/iis:10.0.14393.206

RUN Remove-Website -Name 'Default Web Site'
RUN New-Website -Name 'TestWebApi' -Port 80 \
    -PhysicalPath 'c:\app\TestWebAPI\' -ApplicationPool '.NET v4.5'
EXPOSE 80

CMD Write-Host IIS Started... ; \
    while ($true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 3600 }
```

**I am using following commands to build the app:**

```
 docker image build --tag v2 --file .\Dockerfile .
```

After running the script, I am getting following error:

> 'Remove-Website' is not recognized as an internal or external command

I have seen few people using this command. What is the issue here?

Comment: It's because your default shell is CMD and that is CMDLET from powershell. You would need either to switch shell to powershell or start powershell instead with powershell -command Import-Module webadministration; Remove-Website

Answer (score 0):

**Adding SHELL ["powershell"] fixed the issue.**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY TestWebAPI/*.csproj ./TestWebAPI/
COPY TestWebAPI/*.config ./TestWebAPI/
RUN nuget restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY TestWebAPI/. ./TestWebAPI/
WORKDIR /app/TestWebAPI
RUN msbuild /p:Configuration=Release


FROM microsoft/iis:10.0.14393.206

SHELL ["powershell"]

COPY --from=build /app/TestWebAPI/. ./
RUN Remove-Website -Name 'Default Web Site'
RUN New-Website -Name 'TestWebApi' -Port 80 \
    -PhysicalPath 'c:\appp\TestWebAPI\' -ApplicationPool '.NET v4.5'
EXPOSE 80

CMD Write-Host IIS Started... ; \
    while ($true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 3600 }
```